# Criterion for smooth functions

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, smoothness

Let $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ a real-valued function and $m,n∈\mathbb{N}^∗$ coprime, i.e. greatest common divisor of m and n is 1, and define $f^m:=f\cdot f\cdot\ldots\cdot f.$
Show that 
$$f^m,f^n\in C^\infty\Rightarrow f\in C^\infty.$$ 
I tried to use the fact that every closed subset of a manifold can be expressed as a level set of some smooth real-valued function, but I did not conclude anything.

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com, since it appears to be at the level of an exercise in an introductory textbook.

Comment: Does your $\cdot$ (\cdot) denote the product or the composition? If the product, the problem is (almost) trivial; if the composition, it does not seem trivial to me.

Comment: Maybe...I have founded in some article's remarks and it seems to be true, but I did not found a consistent argument for this.

Comment: What is the article?

Comment: \cdot denote the product, because for composition I am not sure that this statement is true. (I also need the composition, but in this post I tried to find an idea for product case.)

Comment: I do not have an electronic form of the book (or lecture notes more precisely) where I found the suggested question, it is about Differential Operator and Distributions, by Paul Pierre Lévy, from 1946.

Comment: @MarkGrant does not seem so easy for me.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning in the question text itself that the question is easy away from the boundary of the support of $f$. Since $f^m$ is smooth, you can decompose $\mathbb{R}$ into the subsets where $f^m$ is zero and where $f^m$ is non-zero. On the interior of either sets $f$ is clearly smooth (on the latter using that $(f^m)^a (f^n)^b = f$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: If $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ then at least one of them is odd, let's say $m$. It follows that $f = (f^m) ^{\frac 1 m}$, so in particular $f$ is continuous. If $Z = f^{-1} (\{0\})$, then $Z$ is closed and outside of it $f$ is smooth because $x \mapsto x^{\frac 1 m}$ is smooth on $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$. Indeed, the non-trivial part is to study what happens in some neighbourhood of $Z$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: OK, I retracted my vote to close, I hadn't thought carefully enough. stefano: There's a lesson here about MO etiquette - if you phrase your question like a textbook exercise, then some cranky person who hasn't had their coffee might assume that it is one ;)

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Actually, if it were the composition, then the problem is trivial. For a counterexample, take f to be 0 at all rationals, and 1 at all irrationals.

Comment: It is a well-known theorem, but by no means an easy one. Beware: there are several published proofs that are flawed! (however, there are several correct ones too). When I was younger (and smarter), I managed to find yet another one based on Dyn'kin's extension of $C^\infty$ functions with very fast decaying $\bar\partial$ near the real line but that is all I remember now :-(

Comment: @MarkGrant " if you phrase your question like a textbook exercise, then some cranky person who hasn't had their coffee might assume that it is one" I guess the moral is a bit different: don't put your hand on the voting button if you haven't drunk enough coffee or are otherwise in an inappropriate mood to care about the "public good". :-)

Comment: @MichaelRenardy : Good point!

Comment: @fedja : I certainly seem to have underestimated the difficulty of the case when (say) $f(x)=o(|x|)^k$ for each $k>0$ as $x\to0$. Can you give references to some of the correct proofs you mentioned, or maybe to the name of this theorem (if it has one)? Also, why did you spell Dynkin as Dyn'kin? :-)

Comment: @IosifPinelis I wish I remembered that much! Dyn'kin is Евсей Матвеевич Дынькин (who has nothing to do with Dynkin diagrams, etc.)

Comment: See [https://mathoverflow.net/a/127724/26935](https://mathoverflow.net/a/127724/26935) for informations about correct proofs.

Comment: @IosifPinelis In the scientific romanization of Russian the soft sign ь is transliterated by ' . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_transliteration_of_Cyrillic#Table

Comment: Thank you @fedja for clearing up my spelling confusion. I guess I had never before heard of Евсей Матвеевич Дынькин.

Comment: @PietroMajer : Thank you for your comment. I am a native Russian speaker, and I know the transliteration of ь :-). My problem was that I had never before heard of Евсей Матвеевич Дынькин (whose last name should indeed be transliterated as Dyn'kin).

Comment: @PeterMichor : I have looked at "An elementary proof of Joris's theorem" by Robert Myers, which you referred to. However, I cannot see what induction argument he meant in the penultimate sentence of the proof of Case 1, and I don't understand his one-sentence proof of Case 2 at all, which I think is the most difficult one of the three cases. Do you know how to fill in those details?

Comment: @IosifPinelis: the individual in question is [Evsey Dyn'kin](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/MRAuthorID/201472).

Comment: In fact, by the Bézout's identity, one immediately reduces to the case $m=n+1$.

Comment: @WillieWong : Thank you for your comment. Now I know. This was also previously pointed out to me by user fedja.

Comment: The paper "On Joris' theorem on differentiability of functions" by Amemiya and Masuda (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kmj/1138038992) gives a short proof of this result, and it also solves a more general problem posed by Joris.

Comment: @IosifPinelis As far as I remember it, I also had severe problems with Myers' argument (to the extent that I finally gave up and proclaimed it one of the flawed ones). On the bright side, I recalled my homemade contraption with $\bar\partial$. I wanted to post it here, but the question got closed making that impossible during the time I was typing, so I just dumped it to the old thread without any adjustments though the opening phrases may look a bit strange there.

Comment: @fedja : It's good to hear that I am not alone concerning Myers' paper. :-) But I did not understand where one can find your proof -- I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: @IosifPinelis In the thread that is mentioned in the very beginning of the edited version of this question (just follow the link after "this question already has an answer here")

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis Great dialog about this question (in team with fedja, willie wong and others). I also appreciate the proof from Iosif's mentioned article by Amemiya and Masuda. On the other hand, I don't see why the induction (more precisely the inductive step) and the lemma derived from mean value theorem complete the argument from the Myers' paper. But, can an article that is incomplete be published in AMM?

Comment: @fedja Interesting post at the linked question, a little technical but I will try to follow those arguments.

Comment: @stefano "But, can an article that is incomplete be published in AMM". It can. The editor relies on the reviewer, the reviewer knows for sure that the theorem itself is correct and (at least formally) is not obliged to check every detail even in the cases when the result is new, most of the argument makes sense, so... It is neither the first problematic article published in a reputable journal, nor the last one.